# URL Protocol: How to send a parameter with space to run a windows program?

Tags: javascript, html

In the Browser, if I send a URL with a parameter that includes a `space` to a program, the program will get a parameter `%20` and this results in an error.

The parameter is a random parameter, and I can't modify the program to read the parameter, because this program is not developed by me.

Comment: You'll need to modify the program to handle URL encoding. If you can't modify it as you say, you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do about this if you can't modify it. The program apparently does not handle URL encoding, and you will need to modify it to tell it to handle URL encoding, as the `%20` is a space in URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with the following content and save it as `index.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      let query = window.location.search;
      let decoded = decodeURI(query);
      document.write(decoded);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now open the file in the browser and add a query parameter to it, like this:

```
index.html?param=some words
```

The page will show

```
?param=some words
```

You need to tell the programmer that created the page that this is the way to decode correctly.

Actually you need to split the query by ampersand (&) first, and then split each part by equals (=), and then decode each parameter value.